# Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string in Laravel

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel, image-upload

I am trying to upload a form with image using AJAX in my Laravel project. But I have getting error

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string

I can't find the solution.

**html form**

```
<form id="edit_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Image</label>
    <input id="edit_form_image" type="file" class="form-control" name="user_image">
</div><!-- end form-group -->

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input id="edit_form_name" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}">
</div><!-- end form-group -->

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Profession</label>
    <input id="edit_form_profession" type="text" class="form-control"  value="{{Auth::user()->profession}}">
</div><!-- end form-group -->

<button type="button" id="edit_form_submit" class="btn btn-orange">Save Changes</button>
```

**ajax part**

```
$('#signin_button').click(function(event) {

var edit_form_image = $('#edit_form_image').val();
var edit_form_name = $('#edit_form_name').val();
var edit_form_profession = $('#edit_form_profession').val();

$.ajax({

           url:"{{ url('/profile-update') }}",
           data: {image: edit_form_image, name: edit_form_name, profession: edit_foredit_form_professionm_email,  _token: token},
           dataType:'json',
           async:false,
           type: 'POST',
           processData: false,
           contentType: false,
           success:function(msg)
           {
               console.log(msg);
           }                      
       });
```

});

**controller**

```
public function profile_update()
{
$this->validate(request(), [
    'name' => 'required',
    'profession' => 'required'
]);

$imageName = time().'.'.request('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

request()->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

$user = Auth::user();

$user->name = request('name');
$user->profession = request('profession');
$user->avatar = $imageName;

$user->save();

return '1';
```

}

Where is the problem and how to solve that ?

Anybody help please ?

Comment: Show us your full controller.

Comment: you have to use form data instead

Comment: @SalmanZafar...instead of what brother...will u please xplain?

Comment: With ajax only with FormData you can pass an image. Multipart/form-data will not work with AJAX

Comment: @Script47...I have updated my cod with controller

Comment: @ArafatRahman see my answer

Answer (score 0):

To get the file from the request you should use the following code:

```
$imageName = time().'.'.request()->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

This will give you an `UploadedFile` instance, instead of the path.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `formdata` instead

```
$('#signin_button').click(function(event) {

var fd = new FormData();

var edit_form_image = $('#edit_form_image')[0].files;
var edit_form_name = $('#edit_form_name').val();
var edit_form_profession = $('#edit_form_profession').val();

fd.append( 'image', edit_form_image );
fd.append( 'name', edit_form_name );
fd.append( 'profession', edit_form_profession );

$.ajax({

           url:"{{ url('/profile-update') }}",
           data: fd,
           dataType:'json',
           async:false,
           type: 'POST',
           processData: false,
           contentType: false,
           success:function(msg)
           {
               console.log(msg);
           }                      
       });
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late reply brother. I have getting no error while passing data using your code. But how to receive those data in controller ? I have used `request('image')` and also used `Input::hasFile('image')`. But no change.